# React Native: pass touch events through ScrollView to elements lower in the z plane

Tags: animation, react-native, scrollview, parallax

I'm trying to write a parallax element that has multiple panes which scroll at different rates.

To achieve this, I have multiple `View` absolutely positioned and stacked in the z plane, with a `ScrollView` on top to capture the drag events, from which I'll animate the top position and opacity of the lower panes. (Reason for using a `ScrollView` is to benefit from the bouncing and momentum animation that gives us.)

However, the lower panes may contain elements that want to accept touches (as opposed to scrolls). The problem I'm having is that the `ScrollView` captures these touches, and there doesn't seem to be a mechanism to pass them on. Basically, I want the `ScrollView` to respond to drags, but the lower elements to respond to touches.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used https://github.com/rome2rio/react-native-touch-through-view for that on iOS.

However on Android, somehow click events are not getting trough while swiping works for underlying view.